# ESP8266 (Arduino) Using large files

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm working on building a web page on the ESP8266, using the `ESP8266WebServer` library. The problem is with larger html files, I'm not able to load the pages, despite having plenty of program space and memory available.

I believe the issue is an memory overflow in `webserver.send(200,"text/html",htmlDoc);`

Is there a way I can "stitch" the webpage together by breaking the webpage up into smaller pieces?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, you are using the ARDUINO EDI for coding, and using the ESP8266WebServer library.

I have done the same, and noticed, that at ARDUINO EDI 1.65, 
The web-page will produce much more code / RAMusage,
 than using ARDUINO 1.68 or 1.69.

Next, use for static Webpage-Text, the F() function like this

```
 ////////////////////
 // make html footer
 ////////////////////
 void MakeHTTPFooter(void)
{
G_WebSeite += F("\r\n<div style=\"font-size:x-small\">");
G_WebSeite += F("\r\n\t<BR>Aufrufz&auml;hler = ");
G_WebSeite += G_ulReqcount;
G_WebSeite += F("\r\n\t<BR>Uptimez&auml;hler = ");
G_WebSeite += CalcUptime(Guptime);
G_WebSeite += F("\r\n\t<BR>Verbindungsz&auml;hler = ");
G_WebSeite += G_ulReconncount;
G_WebSeite += F("\r\n\t<BR>WiFi-Staerke = ");
G_WebSeite += G_WiFiSignalStrength;
G_WebSeite += F("dbm");
G_WebSeite += F("\r\n\t<BR>Freies RAM = ");
G_WebSeite += (uint32_t)system_get_free_heap_size();
G_WebSeite += F("\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>");
delay(1);
}
```

To save RAM.

To send the Webpage, I have seen some code where the Large web page is
streamt in short pieces to the Client.

Sorry but I have not stored the link, please search here the Internet, 
for Streaming large Webpages.

I hope this will help you.

Mickbaer 
from Berlin Germany